# Generate a certificate with letsencrypt locally

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm new to generating certificates and using letsencrypt, so I'm not sure if this is a dumb question or even possible.

I want to create a small example webapplication using node.js. And I want to test how to implement https, and how to get a proper certificate.

So I tried to use letsencrypt. But it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using my local machine (win10) and I'm cloning the git. Afterwards I try to execute the command `./letsencrypt-auto` but windows won't recognize the script as a command.

How is it possible to use letsencrypt locally on my win10 machine, where no webserver (usually) is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`letsencrypt-auto` [only works with Apache on Debian-based OSes (for now)](https://letsencrypt.org/howitworks/). There's no way to use it on Windows, yet.

That said, people are trying. You might find [this project](https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple/) interesting. (Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with that and haven't tried it myself.)

Comment: Could I create the certificate on an Debian-based OS and just copy it to any other machine to use it there?

Comment: @Loki Yes, in theory, but keep  in mind that letsencrypt doesn't create generic certificates; it creates certificates for specific domains. If your Windows machine doesn't actually host a given domain, letsencrypt is no better than a self-signed certificate. You can always use OpenSSL if you just need a self-signed cert.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can look at - https://github.com/minio/concert built using golang, you can get a windows binary quite naturally.

#### Install

You need to have golang installed to compile `concert`.

```
$ go get -u github.com/minio/concert
```

#### How to run?

Generates certs in `certs` directory by default.

```
$ sudo concert gen <EMAIL> <DOMAIN>
```

Generate certificates in custom directory.

```
$ sudo concert gen --dir my-certs-dir <EMAIL> <DOMAIN>
```

Renew certificates in `certs` directory by default.

```
$ sudo concert renew <EMAIL>
```

Generate certificates in custom directory.

```
$ sudo concert renew --dir my-certs-dir <EMAIL>
```

Run a server with automatic renewal.

```
$ sudo concert server <EMAIL> <DOMAIN>
```

Comment: `Failed to obtain certificates for Domains: [example-1234.com], with following errors [acme: Error 400 - urn:acme:error:connection - DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for example-1234.com`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `ngrok` to expose your local port `80` and make it available to the world via the secure tunnel on `subdomain.ngrok.io`. There is also a possibility to pass that domain as a CNAME for your own domain name.

All you have to do is:

- Create free account with https://ngrok.com/ It works on all operating systems.
- Run `ngrok http 80` and note your `subdomain.ngrok.io`
- Add the above subdomain to your `/etc/hosts` as `127.0.0.1 subdomain.ngrok.io`. This way you will be able to access that domain locally with SSL, while ngrok will make sure Let's Encrypt is able to access it via the Internet.

Edit: Note that this method might not work reliably. Let's encrypt has 20 certificates [rate limit](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/) per registered domain. Which means up 20 certificates in total can be generated for all ngrok users per week.

Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with `ngrok.io`.